# How to Create New Column in Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I need to create new column in pandas dataframe.

```
df 

Id    Value       
1     >45%         
2     >29%        
3     <30 to >69    
4     >40% to <56% 
5     --
```

df_output:

```
Id    Value         Value2
1     >45%          45%
2     >29%          29%
3     <30 to >69    69
4     >40% to <56%  56%
5     --            NaN
```

In my Dataframe there is column called Value, i need to create new column"Value2" on top that column. In Value2 column i need only one number with suffix (if exist in value column) based on the value column.if there are multiple numbers like Id 3&4, i need the highest one among them.

I tried:

```
df.Value.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

But it only extracts the numbers.

Comment: James, can there also be strings like `<80% and >16%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':['>45%', '<30 to >69', '<80% and >16%', '...']})
def lookup(x):
    m = list(re.finditer(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*%?', x))
    if m:
        return max(m, key=lambda x: float(x.group(1)))[0]
    else:
        return np.nan

df['Value2'] = df['Value'].apply(lookup)
# >>> df
#            Value Value2
# 0           >45%    45%
# 1     <30 to >69     69
# 2  <80% and >16%    80%
# 3            ...    NaN
```

*Details*:

- With `re.finditer`, get all matches of the `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*%?` pattern that extracts one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits (capturing this value into Group 1) and then an optional `%` sign
- The `lookup(x)` method return `np.NaN` if no matches are found, else, it returns the match value that contains the biggest number in Group 1.

*Regex details*:

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits (*int or float number*)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `%?` - an optional `%` sign

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gbH2a5/1).

Comment: thanks for the solution, it is fetching only numbers when number is written like 13 % ---> 13, can we change RE so it can detect the spaces between number & %.

Comment: @JamesLin Yes, add a `\s*`.

Comment: how can we extract negative value with this expression, if we have -0.36 it is giving 0.36, it is missing negative sign.

Comment: @JamesLin `re.finditer(r'(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*%?', x)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use following code in Pandas. Written and tested with shown samples. Using [`df.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function of Pandas.

```
df["Value2"] = df['Value'].str.extract('[<>](\d+[%]?$)', expand=False)
```

Output of DataFrame's Value2 column will be as follows:

```
df["Value2"]
0   45%
1   29%
2   69
3   56%
```

***Explanation of regex:*** matching either `<` OR `>` followed by 1 or more digits followed by %(optional) at end of value; in a capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
df['Value2'] = df['Value'].str.split(r'[<>]').str[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['Value2'] = df['Value'].str.extract(r'(\d+%?)$', expand=False)
```

This pattern will match a sequence of digits at the end of a string, with or without a percent sign at the very end.